# Jquery slide down only if not already visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown, slideup

I have a simple problem using Jquery. I want to display detailed information under menu headings, but the interface isn't so smooth. After a few hours of trying some things out, I've come back to the beginning to see if there is a simple answer

Look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GBkMB/) example

Two problems:

1. If you mouse over several categories at once to get to the category you want, the animation still runs through all of the other animations instead of stopping the other ones and only animating the one that the mouse is currently hovered over.
2. If you mouse over a category that is already open, it still runs the animation, but I only want the animation to run if the content is not already visible. Is there a simple if statement that can do this?

Comment: You get this figure out, you have two/three very usable answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.content').hide();
var $elms = $('.fruit, .vegetable, .dairy');
$elms.hover(function() {
    var $content = $(this).next('.content');
    $content.stop(1, 1).slideToggle(400);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/GBkMB/1/

Edit:

To prevent the content from sliding back up you can nest the `div`s like so:

```
<div class="fruit">fruit
    <div class="content fruit_types">apple<br/>bannana<br/>orange</div>
</div>
<div class="vegetable">vegetable
    <div class="content vegetable_types">celery<br/>lettuce<br/>cucumber</div>
</div>
<div class="dairy">dairy
    <div class="content dairy_types">milk<br/>cheese<br/>butter</div>
</div>
```

jQ:

```
$('.content').hide();
var $elms = $('.fruit, .vegetable, .dairy');
$elms.hover(function() {
    var $content = $(this).children('.content'); //<-`children()` not `next()`
        $content.stop(1,1).slideToggle(400);

});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/GBkMB/5/

Comment: a very elegant way! (I saw what was there before your edit...)

Comment: There's a problem with this... If you hover off to the following content it slides back up...

Comment: He's example works like that too. I don't know if this is the expected behavior. It's pretty easy to fix, just nest the divs and done. See edit.

Comment: nesting the divs is an okay way to do it, but if he can't change the HTML structure if he's in a rigid framework, he'll have to use event detection

Comment: What about just wrapping them with jQ? `$elms.each(function(){ var $content = $(this).next('.content').detach(); $(this).append($content); });`

Comment: Also, the use of "hover()" vs "on()" should be inspected by the OP

Comment: If there's no event delegation then either of those is fine. `hover` is just a shortcut.

Comment: @elclanrs this adds a tun of processing, as it has to parse each and set more event listeners. On the fiddler scale this poses no issue. but in a production environment it can be very heavy anytime you parse the DOM then use a .each() also on multiple elements where usually the closure handles that.

Comment: actually if you AJAX a list in, or you add a ".content" to the DOM after the document.ready, the "hover()" won't work on the new elements, you need to use .on() the correct way, I'll edit my answer to show an example.

Comment: @elclanrs I like your elegant answer, and you're right, it's just one example of many on how to accomplish what he's doing... I was just trying to give a little insight into performance for the OP as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your fiddle now to look like this. Should give you an idea of what you want to move forward:

http://jsfiddle.net/GBkMB/4/

```
$("body").on("hover", ".fruit, .vegetable, .dairy", function(event){
  if(event.relatedTarget != $(this).next(".content")[0]){
      if(event.type == "mouseenter"){
         $('.content').slideUp('slow');
         $('.'+$(this).attr("class")+'_types').slideDown('slow');
      }else if(event.type == "mouseleave"){
         $('.content').slideUp('slow');
      }
  }              
});
$("body").on("mouseleave", ".content", function(event){
    if(event.relatedTarget != $(this).prev("div")[0]){
      $(this).slideUp('slow');           
    }
});
```

or: http://jsfiddle.net/GBkMB/6/ @elclanrs answer ++

```
$('.content').on("mouseleave", function(event){
   if(event.relatedTarget != $(this).prev("div")[0]){
      $(this).slideUp('slow');           
    }
});
var $elms = $('.fruit, .vegetable, .dairy');
$elms.on("hover", function(event) {
    var $content = $(this).next('.content');
    if(event.relatedTarget != $content[0]){
        $content.stop(1,1).slideToggle(400);
    }
});
```